# Step Functions - Access State from previous Map Iteration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

How can I get the results from previous `Map` `Iterations` in the next iteration when using `MaxConcurrency: 1` in Amazon Step Functions?

Here's an example of the code I have

```json
{
  "StartAt": "UploadUsers",
  "States": {
    "UploadUsers": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "MaxConcurrency": 1,
      "ItemsPath": "$.data.users",
      "Parameters": {
        "data.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value.data",
        "friends.$": "$.?????? Get created users ids"
      },
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "UploadUser",
        "States": {
          "UploadUser": {
            "End": true,
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "${FnUploadUser}",
              "Payload": {
                "data.$": "$.user_data",
                "friends.$": "$.??????"
              }
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
            "ResultPath": "$.data. ???",
            "Type": "Task"
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "ResultPath": "$.data.UploadUsers",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "result.$": "$"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose `FnUploadUser` is a lambda that returns the id of the created user.
And I want to get the ids of the previously created users and use that value for the next user I'm about to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  `Map` State iterations don't share state. Two workarounds:

**(1) Manage the shared state externally:**  Each `Map` iteration writes and reads from, say, a DynamoDB table.

**(2) Refactor to a "for" loop** and keep the shared state in the execution output.

1. Instead of using `Map`, insert a `Choice` State (after `UploadUser`) that checks for a "done" condition.  If "done", finish, else loop back to `UploadUser`.
2. `UploadUser` accepts the `user_data` array as input.  It appends its output to, say, the `uploaded` output array.
3. Each `UploadUser` iteration identifies the next `user_data` item by comparing it to the `uploaded` array.  The iteration that processes the last item can also output `done: true` to signal to `Choice` that work is done.
4. The `Choice` State loops back to `UploadUser` while there are more to process (i.e. while `done` is not present).

There are other ways to build steps 2-3.  For instance, you could add `next_item` and `total_items` keys on the output to keep track of progress.  The important point is that `Choice` loops until an exit condition is met.

Comment: yeah I came to the same solution (number 2). Thanks for the detailed response.